# How to stay in the current form after assigning a record to me Dynamics CRM 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

My question is : When I assign me a record as shown in following screenshot:
[image]

I want to stay in the form of the record and not go back to the list of records.

How Can I do it, do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there isn't a configuration available to change the behavior of the dialog box.

Create a cloned Assign to Me Button in the Command bar, and have it tied to custom javascript to create a SOAP request to assign the current record to the current user.